# Command blocks placing blocks far away in PE

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I am trying to make a world that clones some blocks, and places them far away.  I am using the latest Bedrock Edition.  World spawn point command doesn’t load the chunks that I want to place in.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: There's `/tickingarea` in MCPE, have you tried that?

Comment: What do I put in ‘y’?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a ticking area where you want to place the blocks with the [/tickingarea](https://www.digminecraft.com/game_commands/tickingarea_command.php) command

This command will keep the specified area loaded